# JQuery animate speed issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` which I want to show on scroll and hide when user scroll back, its working but not as expected. The problem is when I scroll down then it appears fine, but when I scroll back there is a delay in hide.

What I want is show `div` with slide from top to bottom, and when hiding bottom to top effect.

Here is the code I have been trying:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var fheader = $(".top-header");
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>50)
     {
        $(fheader).animate({top: "0px"},{duration: 100, easing: "linear"});
     }
    else
     {
      $(fheader).animate({top: "-50px"},{duration: 100, easing: "linear"});
     }
 });
```

```css
.top-header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1400px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-header">
   header
</div>
<div class="content">
   this is content
</div>
```

Comment: Standard problem - search in SO for specifics.   You need to *debounce* the scroll event as you're animating on every scroll "tick".  eg if you scroll down, it will fire scroll maybe 100 times before you start scrolling back up - each of those animates needs to complete before the next one.  Debounce will only fire once when you stop scrolling. Add a `console.log("scroll")` inside the handler and you'll see how often it's firing.

Comment: The alternative is to store the previous scroll position and see if it's now over/under the limit and only apply the animate when it goes over/under and not on every call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `stop()` before `animate` to prevent queue exécution :

Here is a working example :

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var fheader = $(".top-header");
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>50)
     {
        $(fheader).stop().animate({top: "0px"},{duration: 100, easing: "linear"});
     }
    else
     {
      $(fheader).stop().animate({top: "-50px"},{duration: 100, easing: "linear"});
     }
 });
```

```css
.top-header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1400px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-header">
   header
</div>
<div class="content">
   this is content
</div>
```